# Return search results with highlighted search text and truncated data

Tags: php, regex, laravel

How can I create a search function in the news table of my database that will return results with highlighted search text and truncated data?
I created function `get_search_text($model,$search_text)`. accepts news model and serach text .

```
function get_search_text($model,$search_text){
if (preg_match("/{$search_text}/i", $model->content))
 {
    return preg_replace("/\w*?$search_text\w*/i", "<span style=\"background-color:yellow\" >$0</span>", $model->content);
 }
}
```

It return whole content of finded news with highlighted  search text . But now how can I return it truncated not whole news . Only truncated text which contain first occurance of searched text

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks like it will work for finding and highlighting the search text in the content column of the news table. To truncate the data, you can use the substr function in PHP to limit the number of characters returned. Here's an updated version of your function that includes truncation:

```
function get_search_text($model, $search_text, $truncated_length = 100) {
// Find the search text in the content column
if (preg_match("/{$search_text}/i", $model->content)) {
    // Highlight the search text
    $highlighted = preg_replace("/\w*?$search_text\w*/i", "<span style=\"background-color:yellow\" >$0</span>", $model->content);
    
    // Truncate the data
    if (strlen($highlighted) > $truncated_length) {
        $highlighted = substr($highlighted, 0, $truncated_length) . '...';
    }
    
    return $highlighted;
}

return null; }
```

This version of the function includes a third optional parameter, $truncated_length, which defaults to 100 characters. You can change this value to truncate the data to the desired length. The function returns the truncated and highlighted text if the search text is found in the content column, and null otherwise.

**Here is an updated version that might solve your mentioned issue:**

```
function get_search_text($model, $search_text, $truncated_length = 100) {
// Find the search text in the content column
if (preg_match("/{$search_text}/i", $model->content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    $match_offset = $matches[0][1];
    // Highlight the search text
    $highlighted = preg_replace("/\w*?$search_text\w*/i", "<span style=\"background-color:yellow\" >$0</span>", $model->content);
    
    // Truncate the data
    if (strlen($highlighted) > $truncated_length) {
        $truncated = substr($highlighted, $match_offset, $truncated_length);
        if ($match_offset > 0) {
            $truncated = '...' . $truncated;
            $truncated_length += 3;
        }
        if ($match_offset + $truncated_length < strlen($highlighted)) {
            $truncated = $truncated . '...';
        }
        $highlighted = $truncated;
    }
    
    return $highlighted;
}

return null;}
```

Regards

Comment: But I also want finded and highlighted text to contain in truncated text . If $truncated_lengt =100 and my finded text position is 200 . So it wont contain in truncated text